# Using a Lazy Load inside a popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, lazy-loading

I tried to implement a Lazy Load inside a popover.
For the lazyload, I use Echo.js (http://toddmotto.com/echo-js-simple-javascript-image-lazy-loading/)

In a table, I've cells like this :

```
<td>
  <a id='pop-ID' class='pop'>
    <img src='loading.gif' data-echo='thumb-image.jpg' class='img-rounded'>
  </a>
</td>
```

As you can see, in my cell, i can see a loading gif, and according to the position the thumb is loaded.
Works pretty well

Now I want to load in a popover the full size image
I want to use quite the same technique to avoid the loading of all the full size images of my page

I keep the same table/cell thing, and add in my page an hidden div including

```
<td>
  <a id='pop-ID' class='pop'>
    <img src='loading.gif' data-echo='thumb-image.jpg' class='img-rounded'>
  </a>
</td>

<div style='display: none;' id='pop-ID_content' class='popSourceBlock'>
  <div class='popTitle'>PopOver Title</div>
  <div class='popContent'>
    <img src='loader.gif' data-echo='image.jpg' class='img-rounded'>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I'm stuck here, I only see the loading gif inside the popover, not the image.jpg I should be able to see

Here is the JS I use for the popover

```
$(".pop").each(function() {
  var $pElem= $(this);
  $pElem.popover(
    { 
      placement: 'left',
      trigger: 'hover',
      html : true,
      title: getPopTitle($pElem.attr("id")),
      content: getPopContent($pElem.attr("id"))
    }
  );
});

function getPopTitle(target) {
  return $("#" + target + "_content > div.popTitle").html();
};

function getPopContent(target) {
  return $("#" + target + "_content > div.popContent").html();
};
```

Do you see what's wrong or what I missed ?

This is pretty my first attempt on this subject, 
so I've read the others threads about, but I couldn't find a way to reproduce the results in my configuration

Comment: It's because normal lazyloader are only re-acting to scroll events and only with static content. Use lazySizes (https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes/), this lazyloader handles dynamic content automatically. Easy.

Answer (score 1):

Using the comment above, I just changed a bit the line related to the image.jpg

```
<td>
  <a id='pop-ID' class='pop'>
    <img src='loading.gif' data-echo='thumb-image.jpg' class='img-rounded'>
  </a>
</td>

<div style='display: none;' id='pop-ID_content' class='popSourceBlock'>
  <div class='popTitle'>PopOver Title</div>
  <div class='popContent'>
    <img data-src='image.jpg' class='lazyload img-rounded'>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now it works, thanks !

I'll try now to use lazysizes more widely to solve my problems